# Is Spark still advantageous for non-iterative analytics?

Tags: apache-spark, analytics, latency, spark-streaming

Spark uses in memory computing and caching to decrease latency on complex analytics, however this is mainly for "iterative algorythms",
If I needed to perform a more basic analytic, say perhaps each element was a group of numbers and I wanted to look for elements with a standard deviation less than 'x' would Spark still decrease latency compared to regular cluster computing (without in memory computing)? Assuming I used that same commodity hardware in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tied for the top sorting framework using none of those extra mechanisms, so I would argue that is reason enough. But, you can also run streaming, graphing, or machine learning without having to switch gears. Then, you add in that you should use DataFrames wherever possible and you get query optimizations beyond any other framework that I know of. So, yes, Spark is the clear choice in almost every instance.

Answer (score 1):

One good thing about spark is its Datasource API combining it with SparkSQL gives you ability to query and join different data sources together. SparkSQL now includes decent optimizer - catalyst. As mentioned in one of the answer along with core (RDD) in spark you can also include streaming data, apply machine learning models and graph algorithms. So yes.